# Still Vaadin 23 support Microsoft Edge?

Tags: vaadin

I'm new to Vaadin and I started with the demo [quick start application](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/guide/quick-start) using the latest version of vaadin (23). It runs fine in chrome and firefox but seems not supported on Microsoft Edge (v. Microsoft Edge 44.19041.423.0).
I read something about but no one solution worked like [this](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17851939/was-vaadin-10-bakery-app-starter-ever-working-in-ms-edge-and-or-ie11).
Still, Vaadin supports M.Edge?

Can anyone help to solve or point me in the right direction?
Thanks

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/vaadin/platform/releases/tag/23.0.0 lists the supported browsers. The evergreen version of Edge is supported, older versions are not.

Answer (score 2):

Vaadin 23 does support the evergreen version of Edge (see [release notes](https://github.com/vaadin/platform/releases/tag/23.0.0)), but as the message says, you're using a too old version. Upgrading the browser should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you said i was using a too old version.
The problem appeared on old windows builds, because windows update is disabled by the customer company antivirus by default and for this reason not even Microsoft Edge was updated and some workstation had an older version of it.
Just upgrading solve the problem, thanks

ps. I edit the title